# [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0125E Function sequence error on RUBY

Tags: ruby, db2

```
require "ibm_db"
=> true

db_config =  {:host=>"ec2-<>.compute.amazonaws.com", :database=>"SAMPLE", :user=>"user", :password=>"pass", :port=>50000}

db_conn = IBM_DB.connect("DATABASE=#{db_config[:database]};HOSTNAME=#{db_config[:host]};PORT=#{db_config[:port]};PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=#{db_config[:user]};PWD=#{db_config[:password]};AUTHENTICATION=SERVER;ClientWrkStnName=tester", "", "")
=> #<IBM_DB::Connection:0x00007fa563fbc8f8>

IBM_DB.autocommit(db_conn)
=> 1

IBM_DB.autocommit(db_conn,0)
=> true

IBM_DB.autocommit(db_conn)
=> 0

sql = "INSERT INTO TTE (name, price) VALUES (?,?)"  

stmt = IBM_DB.prepare(db_conn, sql)
#<IBM_DB::Statement:0x00007fa564ce28c0>

value = "string"
IBM_DB.bind_param(stmt,1,value)  
(pry):12: warning: Describe Param Failed: [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0125E  Function sequence error. SQLSTATE=HY010 SQLCODE=-99999
=> false
```

tried another way

```
 param = ["sr", 1]
=> ["sr", 1]
IBM_DB.execute(stmt, param)

(pry):14: warning: Execute Failed due to: [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0125E  Function sequence error. SQLSTATE=HY010 SQLCODE=-99999
=> false
```

Getting CLI0125E  Function sequence error for both ways. Not sure how to resolve it.

I'm on Mac catalina, using ibm_db (3.0.5)

.zschrc

```
export IBM_DB_HOME=/Applications/dsdriver
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/dsdriver/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/dsdriver/lib
```

Comment: What is the schema of TTE? Which version of Db2?

Comment: Please improve your question by adding the version of ruby, and also add the version of the IBM data server driver (run its `db2level` command and copy/paste its plain text output into your question).  The CLI0125E is normally caused by a programming error.  Please also mention the reason you did not use clidriver.   Please also mention if you can connect (with  the `db2cli` tool at the zsh command line to the same database with the same credentials. Refer to docs to see how to connect with the `db2cli` tool for example `db2cli validate -dsn ... -connect -user ... -passwd ...`

Comment: Your sample works for me locally linux, with ruby 2.5.1p57 and db2 ds driver 11.5.7.0. Suggest you look under the covers with the `db2trc` command. `db2trc on -f trc.dmp`  ;` irb` (run your sample to recreate the symptom) ; `db2trc off` ; `db2trc fmt trc.dmp trc.fmt` ; `db2trc flw trc.dmp trc.flw` ; `db2trc fmt -c trc.dmp trc.fmtc` ; `db2trc fmt -cli trc.dmp trc.cli` . Then create a new issue on github ruby-ibmdb, attaching the files trc.fmt, trc.fw, trc.fmtc, trc.cli as produced by the db2trc commands shown. If you understand CLI, you might also see the error by studying the files yourself.

Comment: Oh sorry there is a mismatch in the table schema. Corrected the schema and it works! @data_henrik thanks

Comment: @mao Thanks for trying to help. It was my mistake. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

There was a mismatch in the table scheme. The field price was not present. Corrected the table schema and the query is working.